# Avoid multiple $http.get in async service

Tags: angularjs

I've created a service that fetches through $http.get().

My service is used in a directive that renders to several ui elements. The service is async. It's used in the directive code like: myService.getStuff(), and it returns a customized promise (from within the callbacks of the $http.get promise).

But I want my service to only perform one call to $http.get during the lifecycle of the app. And cache the http.get response.

So say I use the directive 2 times in my html. Then this is what I want: The first time it's called it (returns immediately and) fetches stuff via $http.get. The second time it's called it detects an outstanding call to $http.get. thus does not do another call to $http.get, but somehow awaits the return of the first call.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use the internal [cache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching) of `$http`

```
return $http.get(/*...*/, { cache: true }).then(/*...*/);
```

or just cache the promise in your service.

```
function MyService($http) {
   var promise;

   this.get = function() {
      promise = promise || $http.get(/*...*/).then(/*...*/);
      return promise;
   }
}
```

If you're using uirouter, another way is to [`resolve`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider) the data in a parent state, and inject the resolved data to all your components.

Comment: You have a spurious extra `var` inside the function. It needs to just be an assignment to the outer `promise` variable.

Comment: so setting cache: true, won't work in my case since what I want to avoid is calling $http.get(), regardless of if it internally caches the response.
But as you write caching the promise in my service might be more along the lines. This means that I would return the same promise several times and set different callback functions to it each time the service is called. Is this fine?

Answer (score 0):

Set `cache` to `true` like this:

```
$http.get(yourUrl, {cache: true})
    .then(...)
```

Any subsequent call to this will use the cached value.